# Unable to find an instance for the variable x, even with explicit instantiation

Tags: coq

I'm currently working through the [Logical Foundations book](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html) and I'm stuck on the last part of [Exercise: 4 stars, advanced (subsequence)](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/IndProp.html) (subseq_trans).

Here is my definition for subseq:

```
Inductive subseq { X : Type } : list X -> list X -> Prop :=
  | s1 : forall l, subseq [] l
  | s2 : forall (x : X) (l l': list X), subseq l l' -> subseq l (x :: l')
  | s3 : forall (x : X) (l l' : list X), subseq l l' -> subseq (x :: l) (x :: l').
```

And here is my proof for subseq_trans:

```
Theorem subseq_trans : forall (X : Type) (l1 l2 l3 : list X),
   subseq l1 l2 -> subseq l2 l3 -> subseq l1 l3.
Proof.
  intros X l1 l2 l3 H H'.
  generalize dependent H.
  generalize dependent l1.
  induction H'.
  { intros l1 H. inversion H. apply s1. }
  { intros l1 H. apply s2. apply IHH'. apply H. }
  { intros l1 H. apply s2. apply IHH'. apply s2 in H. (* Unable to find an instance for the variable x. *) }
```

Here is the proof context before the failed apply:

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
l, l' : list X
H' : subseq l l'
IHH' : forall l1 : list X, subseq l1 l -> subseq l1 l'
l1 : list X
H : subseq l1 (x :: l)
______________________________________(1/1)
subseq l1 l
```

I have tried explicitly instantiating x like this:

```
apply s2 with (x:=x) in H
```

But that gives me:

```
No such bound variable x (possible names are: x0, l0 and l'0).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the answers below resolve your problem?

Comment: I guess I was a bit of a victim of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, in the sense that direction of my proof was wrong (I figured out the solution by now). However, it was interesting to read about eapply and a bit of coq internals, which I think will definitely come in handy at some point in the future.

Comment: For reference: what I expected to happen was that `apply s2 with (x:=x) in H` would turn `H : subseq l1 (x :: l)` into `H : subseq l1 l`. But this stemmed from a wrong interpretation of how apply works in hypotheses.

Comment: Exactly. It's the difference between reasoning forward from the hypotheses and backwards from the goal. I preferred to answer your specific question rather than ruin the fun of completing the exercise. Still, I wouldn't hesitate to accept one of the answers and upvote both! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [eapply](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.eapply) tactic useful to see what is going on.

```
...
{ intros l1 H. apply s2. apply IHH'. eapply s2 in H.
```

gives `subseq l1 (?1 :: x :: l)`, where you can instantiate the `?1` with whatever you want, but, as you can now see, applying `s2` *forward* from that assumption doesn't advance the proof.

Another possibility is to apply `s2` to `x` and then to the assumption `H`:

```
apply (s2 x) in H.
```

I also find it strange that `apply s2 with (x:=x)` does not work. Coq seems to be doing some renaming behind the scenes, probably to avoid confusion with the `x` in the proof context. The following sequence applies without error:

```
rename x into y. apply s2 with (x:=y) in H.
```

Answer (score 2):

As diagnosed by @tbrk, this is a renaming done by Coq in the presence of maximal implicit arguments (see [this issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4536)). This is due to the declaration of `{X : Type}` in the definition of `subsequence`.

One solution is to use `@` to turn all implicit arguments to non-implicit and avoid this renaming issue. This would give:

```
apply @s2 with (x:=x) in H.
```